# How do I analyse if y is significantly decreasing or remain constant with increasing x?

Tags: r, regression

Can someone advise how to analyse if y is significantly decreasing with increasing x using R?

```
y=c(111.8784966,91.79114434,90.02533714,86.30424896,82.35746173,84.31890131)

SEy=c(27.43598893,13.38661564,15.35877537,12.9718339,9.933174075,7.232236469)

x=c(0.04,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.2)

df=data.frame(y,SEy,x)
```

SEy is standard error for y

The regression I did is

```
lm1 <- lm(y~log(x))
```

The plot is show below. The bar indicates standard error of y.

[image]

Can I just try finding the 95% confidence interval (CI) of each y and check if the first CI of y overlaps with the second CI of y? and if overlaps, it means P>0.05?

Here's the original data:

```
y1=c(139.3144855,105.17776,105.3841125,99.27608286,92.29063581,91.55113778)

y2=c(84.4425076,78.4045287,74.6665618,73.3324151,72.4242877,77.0866648)
```

y1 and y2 are measurements taken for sample 1 and sample 2 respectively.

Following the solution given by @user2974951 below, I edited (13 Feb 2022) the post to include the plot:

```
library(ggeffects)

mixed.lme <- lme(y~log(x),random=~1|b,data=df)
pred.mm <- ggpredict(mixed.lme, terms = c("x"))

(ggplot(pred.mm) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +          # slope
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = predicted - std.error, ymax = predicted + std.error), 
                fill = "lightgrey", alpha = 0.5) +  # error band
    geom_point(data = df,                      # adding the raw data (scaled values)
               aes(x = x, y = y, shape = b)) + 
    labs(x = "x", y = "y", 
         title = "") + 
    theme_minimal()
)
```

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235693/linear-model-where-the-data-has-uncertainty-using-r/235731

Comment: What are those SEy's? How did you obtain them? Are these measurement errors obtained together with the measurement? Or are these errors obtained after some grouping?

Comment: @user2974951 each y values are mean of 2 replicates and hence the standard error I posted above.

Comment: Why did you group your data? Why not analyse the raw ungrouped data? Then you wouldn't have to estimate any SE and somehow include them in the model.

Comment: I think I understood what you mean now but just to double confirm, you're saying analysing the raw data and as what you explained below, if slope is significantly different from zero, then y is significantly decreasing with increasing x? Correct?

Comment: This is only valid if your individual data points are independent replicates not just 'technical' replicates of measurement.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva It's two replicates from two samples of the same batch. So I guess it's considered independent replicates?

Comment: Could you explain the study design a bit better, is `x` a variable you control like a treatment?  Are the samples for the other values of `x` also drawn from the same batch?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Sure. x is an environmental factor that we control in the chamber where the sample was exposed to and we measured y to understand how it change with x.

Comment: Can you post your original data with this additional information about the batch? This sounds like a variable that should be included in your model. Somehow it sounds like these measurements belong together, otherwise you would have not put them in the same batch.

Comment: agree wih @user2974951 knownig how the batches and samples are related is important here.

Comment: Thanks @user2974951. I have edited my question to include the original data as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your new data, I think that the best course of action is to consider that these two measurements, y1 and y2, were taken in batches and so should be treated as such, i.e. coming from the same batch which may have some intra-variation. To model this intra-variation you can use a mixed model, with the batches variable as a random effect rather than a fixed effect.

```
df=data.frame(
  "y"=c(y1,y2),
  "x"=rep(x,2),
  "b"=rep(c("A","B"),each=length(x))
)

library(nlme)
summary(lme(y~log(x),random=~1|b,data=df))
```

which results in

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  85.95703 87.16737 -38.97851

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | b
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    20.05997 8.319754

Fixed effects: y ~ log(x) 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  49.85733 17.941340  9  2.778908  0.0214
log(x)      -18.10234  4.703894  9 -3.848373  0.0039
(truncated)
```

The slope is still in log(x), telling you it is negative and equal to roughly -18, with a p-value of <0.05. Additionally, if this is of interest to you, you could check how much variation is due to the batches (out of the whole), in your case about 20.1 out of 20.1+8.32, so roughly 71 %.

Comment: Hi @user2974951, I'm revisiting this topic. How do I know how well the model fit my data? I don't find r-squared from the summary. Can you please advise?

Comment: @Catalyst If your goal is to assess model fit then I would suggest you look at the AIC/BIC criterion, which are provided in the summary, and forget about R-squared (in general, I do not think R-square is a good measure of fit). If you would like to learn more about this topic see [When AIC and Adjusted R2 lead to different conclusions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140965/when-aic-and-adjusted-r2-lead-to-different-conclusions?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks @user2974951. I now have an improved understanding on AIC/BIC criterion.